# How to convert video into frames using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to convert video into frames using MATLAB? Is there any specific requirement of any other software to be installed on my PC? And how to setup MATLAB for this conversion? And can we do same with any other tool?

I am using MATLAB 2011. I have tried this code:

```
 vid=mmreader('C:\Users\Hardik\Desktop\Practicles\Seminar\Video\Charlie Chaplin - The Lion Cage.3gp');
 numFrames = vid.NumberOfFrames;
 n=numFrames;
 for i = 1:2:100
 frames = read(vid,i);
 imwrite(frames,['Image' int2str(i), '.jpg']);
 im(i)=image(frames);
 end
```

It is showing following error:

```
Error in ==> cbvr at 6
 imwrite(rgb2gray,['Image' int2str(i), '.jpg']);`enter code here`
```

Comment: Try changing '['Image' int2str(i), '.jpg']' in line 6 to 'strcat('Image', num2str(i), '.jpg')'

Comment: @Hwathanie it is still not working..do i have to add any extension to matlab.??

Comment: @Hwathanie this is the error   cbvr
Warning: Unable to determine the number of frames in this file. 
??? Error using ==> imwrite at 457
Can't open file "image1.jpg" for writing.
You may not have write permission.

Error in ==> cbvr at 6
 imwrite(frames,strcat('image',num2str(i), '.jpg'));

Comment: Pls try this, 'imwrite(frames,strcat('Image', num2str(i), '.jpg')','jpg')'.

Comment: @Hwathanie how to solve this error..Can't open file "Image1.jpg" for writing.
You may not have write permission.

Comment: Your code works fine in my PC. I only changed 'mmreader' to 'VideoReader' as 'mmreader' does not support in my Matlab version. May be try this 'imwrite(frames,strcat('C:\Users\Hardik\Desktop\Practicles\Seminar\Video\Image', num2str(i), '.jpg')','jpg')'.

Comment: ok ..now it is working..i have updated matlab...